# Predicting NA values with a perfect line in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

In my dataset, column A and B are strongly correlated and the scatter plot is as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = B, y =A)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

A is inversely proportional to B and forms a perfect nonlinear line.

Yet in column B, there are some missing values NA and I would like to replace them while keeping the perfect line instead of dropping them or replacing them by mean.

Here is my attempt to calculate the value directly but this approach doesn't work very well.

```
const = mean(transform(df, new = A* B)$new)
df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- const / df$A
```

It looks like this.
[image]

Instead of calculating it, is there a way to do so?
For example, how to replace the missing values with a predict() function ?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe the naniar package can help you https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/getting-started-w-naniar.html

Answer (score 1):

In the question, the last assignment is forgetting

1. To set `mean` argument `na.rm = TRUE`;
2. to subset column `A`, only the values for which `B` is missing should be taken into account.

In the example below I have created the data with `const = pi`.

```
f <- function(x, const = 1) const/x

const <- with(df1, mean(A*B, na.rm = TRUE))
const
#[1] 3.141593

na <- is.na(df1$B)
df1$B[na] <- f(df1$A[na], const = const)
plot(B ~ A, df1)
```

---

### Test data

```
x <- seq(0.1, 2, by = 0.01)
y <- f(x, pi)
set.seed(2021)
is.na(y) <- sample(length(y), 0.1*length(y))
df1 <- data.frame(A = x, B = y)
```

Comment: Your code works but this approach doesn't work very well. i think it's because it is not strictly a constant

Comment: @user16971617 In that case you must revise the question. If it's a moving average or linear or quadratic interpolation, that must be said in the question.